# how to create a auto closing messagebox in java

Tags: java

i want to create a messagebox which will be automatically close without users input. i tried reading couple of java tutorials. its a timer class. but i couldnt find the code examples.

can someone please help me to do it. a small code example would be great

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something along these lines:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class AutoDismiss implements ActionListener
{
    private JDialog dialog;

    private AutoDismiss(JDialog dialog)
    {
        this.dialog = dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent)
    {
        dialog.dispose();
    }

    public static void showMessageDialog(Component parentComponent,
                                         String message, String title,
                                         int delayInMilliseconds)
    {
        final JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane(message);
        final JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog(parentComponent, title);
        dialog.setTitle(title);
        Timer timer = new Timer(delayInMilliseconds, new AutoDismiss(dialog));
        timer.setRepeats(false);
        timer.start();
        if (dialog.isDisplayable())
        {
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: im using JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you.. Next Customer Please..");

this messagebox. but is there way to close this messagebox from a certain time. please help me

Comment: Not that I know of, not with that call, unless you can find some way of getting hold of the JDialog. It's probably simplest to change your call to create JOptionPane use the class I posted above, which I've edited. It can then be used as a dropin replacement.